# Interactively communicating with a FORTRAN shell program

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pexpect

DAOPHOT is a FORTRAN-written software for performing astronomy tasks in images. A typical flow of its usage is:

1. Open a terminal (gnome-terminal in my case) and run `./daophot`. I'm now within DAOPHOT's shell.
2. Prompts the user for a command, let's say `ATTACH` to input an image file. DAOPHOT runs and prompts the user again for more commands.
3. User gives another command, let's say `PHOTOMETRY`. DAOPHOT runs and prompts the user again.

For every command the user gives, DAOPHOT runs and prompts again and again until `exit` is typed. For my case, I have three specific commands that will run one after another, without variation (`ATTACH`, `PHOTOMETRY` and `PSF`, with the latter maybe run more than once).

Right now I'm simply trying to `ATTACH` a file. What I have tried:

Using `subprocess`, as seen/asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880190/interactive-input-output-using-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457931/running-an-interactive-command-from-within-python):

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal","--disable-factory","--","./daophot"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(input("ATTACH file.fits"))
```

For this case, DAOPHOT's shell opens but the ATTACH command is not executed. I close the shell and the string "ATTACH file.fits" appears in the IPython terminal, ending the subprocess. I've tried also to use `p.communicate(input=input("ATTACH file.fits"))`, but got the same result.

Using `pexpect`, as seen/asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967099/how-to-automate-shell-interactive-commands-using-python-pexpect-module) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371249/using-expect-and-interact-simultaneously-in-pexpect):

```
import pexpect

p = pexpect.spawn("gnome-terminal --disable factory -- ./daophot")
p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
p.sendline("ATTACH file.fits")
```

In this case, DAOPHOT's shell opens but the ATTACH command is not accounted for as an input.

Finally, a DAOPHOT wrapper already [exists](https://pypi.org/project/astwro/), but the idea is to have this automatically and interactive Python version in our lab, so that we can change later if needed.

From what I understand in terms of pipelines, `./daophot` is a subsubprocess runnning inside `gnome-terminal`, so when I use e.g. `p.stdin.write(input("ATTACH file.fits")` I am actually inputing this command into `gnome-terminal`, and not into `./daophot`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can probably write commands to a text file and then redirect it into daophot like `./daophot << commands.txt`? I've found this works well with a bunch of other programs that take commands on `stdin`, such as `xfoil`, but _it isn't strictly "interactive"_

Comment: Or you could directly spawn daophot as a subprocess instead of through the terminal? Great first question BTW. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, thanks for the reply. When I run `./daophot` directly as a subprocess I can't see its development in real time, which happens in the terminal and is essential to spot unwanted values during the computation.